# Credit card payment on delivery

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

In **magento checkout page** i want `Credit card payment on delivery` like `the cash on delivery`

Is anyone implemented this **Credit card payment on delivery** please help me

Also please provide links for reffering

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you need?? just register when is this kind of payment or something else? Some business rules?? What you have tryed? Post some code.

Comment: credit card or cash on delivery or both ?

Comment: You can have the Credit CArd Saved and Money Order options enabled. Does that fit your requirment?

Comment: hai all 
i want to know is it possible to add credit card payment on delivery
ie like the cash on delivery

Comment: @rs the credit card/cash on delivery is done merchant -to - customer via on delivery
so some customers have credit card with them

Comment: You can do this without problem. Its quite simple.

Comment: @Guerra please provide the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just code, yes it's possible do that.

basically you just need a model like these:
The basic structure to payment module is (i'll show example with basic payment with 1 additional information field:

```
Module
------->Block
------------->Form
------------------->Pay.php
------------->Info
------------------->Pay.php
------->etc
------------->config.xml
------------->system.xml
------->Model
------------->Paymentmethodmodel.php
```

Important things about this module:

```
Yourpaymentmodule_Block_Form_Pay
```

This block make the frontend view. The code:

```
<?php
class YourPaymentModule_Block_Form_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
protected function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('yourpaymentmodule/form/pay.phtml');
}
}
```

The other one is Yourpaymentmodule_Block_Info_Pay, this one make the view from Admin Order Details.

```
<?php
class YourPaymentModule_Block_Info_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{
protected function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('yourpaymentmodule/form/pay.phtml');
}

protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
{
    if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
        return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
    }
    $info = $this->getInfo();
    $transport = new Varien_Object();
    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
    $transport->addData(array(
        Mage::helper('payment')->__('Additional Information') => $info->getAdditional(),
    ));
    return $transport;
}
}
```

And finally on your model:

```
<?php 
class PPaymentModuleName_Model_PaymentModuleName extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'custompaymentmodule';
    protected $_formBlockType = 'custompaymentmodule/form_pay';
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'custompaymentmodule/info_pay';
    protected $_canUseInternal              = true;
    protected $_canOrder                    = true;

public function assignData($data)
{
    if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
        $data = new Varien_Object($data);
    }
    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();
    $info->setAdditionalINformation($data->getAdditionalINformation());
    return $this;
}

public function canUseForCountry($country)
{
    return true;
}

public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode){
    return true;
}
}
    ?>
```

On your phtml files you make the design, just simple field or something.

Other important thing is in your etc/modules/CustomPaymentModule.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <CustomPaymentModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
        <depends> 
            <Mage_Payment /> 
        </depends> 
    </CustomPaymentModule>
</modules>
</config>
```

And this is it.